# how to restrict the dragable & scalled item using CSS transform, translate below the div boundary?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, translate

Git repo for the code
https://github.com/time-to-program/create-image-zoom-in-out-react-js

[show with arrow the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO1qW.png)
how to restrict this dragable to not go below the parent container?

can anyone suggest any solution to restrict this max until boundary of the parent?
can anyone suggest any solution to restrict this max until boundary of the parent?

Comment: pls. take a look [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get more attention to your question